# Jersey2: Consumes APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED and MULTIPART_FORM_DATA together

Tags: java, forms, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I'm using Jersey the first time.

I just want my service accepts both `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` and `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` post form, just like that in Django or php.

Even better, I want the `APPLICATION_JSON` can also works.

So I tried the code below in my `UserResource` class:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User createUser(
        @FormDataParam("username") @FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormDataParam("password") @FormParam("password") String password,
        @FormDataParam("mobile") @FormParam("mobile") String mobile,
        @FormDataParam("email") @FormParam("email") String email) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setMobile(mobile);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPlainPassword(password);
    userDao.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

Then I success with `x-www-url-form-urlencoded` submit, but when I submit with `multipart/formdata`, it goes down:

[image]

And when I remove the `@FormParam` annotation, it cannot accept `x-www-url-form-urlencoded` submit, and shows:

[image]

---

So here's my question:

#### 1. Is there any way to make them work together?

#### 2. Is there any Param type like `@JsonParam` that accepts request form type of `application/json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution myself:

Jersey routes the request with different `@{METHOD}`, `@Consumes` and `@Path`.

So if we declare two different method, which has same `@POST` method, same `@Path("/")`, but different `@Consumes` in our resource:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User create(
        @FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("password") String password,
        @FormParam("mobile") String mobile,
        @FormParam("email") String email) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setMobile(mobile);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPlainPassword(password);
    userDao.save(user);
    return user;
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User createUser(
        @FormDataParam("username") String username,
        @FormDataParam("password") String password,
        @FormDataParam("mobile") String mobile,
        @FormDataParam("email") String email) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setMobile(mobile);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPlainPassword(password);
    userDao.save(user);
    return user;
}
```

See, then when we make a request which Content-Type equals `x-www-form-urlencoded`, the request is then route into the first method. Or when we post the same url with `Content-Type` equals `multipart/formdata`, the request will then route to the second.

And we can separately code the dealing work, which uses either `@FormParam` or `@FormDataParam`, but never both.

Answer (score 0):

Please use consume as  `@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})`.
So that endpoint can accept both multipart object and form data as follows

```
@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
@FormDataParam("email") String email)
```

Please test it from postman as form data and file should be type 'file' and email should be type 'text'

[image]

Comment: Still returns *"HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type"* when submit with `x-www-url-form-urlencoded` in my case, I don't know why.

Comment: please ensure your trying post request, as per your implementation you need to call post

Comment: You can't make a call to this resource from the browser (simply paste url in the address bar) as it is posted, the browser makes get request only.

Comment: How are you testing? Can you please try it from postman or poster or any other client.

Comment: Yes, the screenshots in the question is from postman, if I use your method, and post body using `form-data`, it's ok. But I got 415 error when using `x-www-url-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: are you trying as form-data.see my attachment

Comment: I just want it work well on both `form-data` and `x-www-url-form-urlencoded`